# ApexChart data have mismatched y-axis

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm playing with the apexchart.js library and getting this mismatched graph. I want to display an area graph, where the X line is a collection of date-times and the Y line has some values (floating type).

On the picture, you can see the library set the bad zero point for some series.

[image: ApexChart]

Here are my settings for the graph.

```html
let options = {
        chart: {
            height: 390,
            type: 'area',
            stacked: false
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Power – Total",
            data: powerTotal,
            type: 'area'
        },
        {
            name: "Power – Solar A",
            data: powerSolarA,
            type: 'area'
        },
        {
            name: "Power – Solar B",
            data: powerSolarB,
            type: 'area'
        },
        {
            name: "Consumption",
            data: consumption,
            type: 'area'
        },
        {
            name: "Battery",
            data: batteryPower,
            type: 'area'
        },
        {
            name: "Grid",
            data: gridPower,
            type: 'area'
        },
        ],
        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            categories: datetimes,
            labels: {
                datetimeUTC: false
            }
        },
        yaxis: [
            {
                seriesName: 'Power – Total',
                title: {
                    text: "kW"
                },
                decimalsInFloat: 2,
                showAlways: true,
                floating: false,

            },
            {
                seriesName: 'Power – Solar A',
                show: false,
                floating: false,

            },
            {
                seriesName: 'Power – Solar B',
                show: false,
                floating: false,
            },
            {
                seriesName: 'Consumption',
                show: false,
                floating: false,
            },
            {
                seriesName: 'Battery',
                show: false,
                floating: false,
            },
            {
                seriesName: 'Grid',
                show: false,
                floating: false,
            },
        ],
        markers: {
            size: 0,
            hover: {
                size: undefined,
                sizeOffset: 3
            }
        },
        colors: lineColors,
        tooltip: {
            x: {
                format: "dd:MM:yyy HH:mm"
            }
        },
        fill: {
            opacity: .6,
            type: 'solid'
        },
        stroke: {
            show: true,
            curve: 'straight',
            width: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]
        },
        grid: {
            show: true
        },
        legend: {
            itemMargin: {
                vertical: 24
            }
        }
    };
```

Does anybody know what it can be?
Thanks